# How to write the transient analysis ltspice directive with a stop time and start saving data time?

Tags: ltspice

How to include 0.9m start saving data in spice directive?

.trans 1m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click with the mouse on the text `.trans 1m` and change it in the dialog box as shown below.

The LTspice directive becomes `.tran 0 1m .9m`

Explanation of the preceeding zero:
The syntax is: `.TRAN <Tstep> <Tstop> [Tstart [dTmax]] [modifiers]`
If Tstart or dTmax is specified, Tstep must has to be specified as well. Tstep is the plotting increment for the waveforms but is also used as an initial step-size guess. LTspice uses waveform compression, so this parameter is of little value and can be omitted or set to zero.

[image]

Comment: unfortunately, im using the mac version of ltspice which doesn't have the edit simulation command menu, am I right?

Comment: @www That's why I added the new spice directive as well. I was already thinking it had to be someting like that. Why would someone ask something very basic for LTspice under Windows?

Comment: So if the stop is 1m and start saving data is 0.9m, the directive is  `.trans 0 1m .9m` But when I checked the result, why it still shows the data before 0.9m?

Comment: In case the help file doesn't work under Mac, you might be interested in: http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelpXVII/LTspiceHelp.html .. do check the whole site, it's interesting :)

Comment: @www Note that the **plot window always** starts at 0 (and not at e.g. 0.9 msec). Are you sure the window shows the data before this 0.9 ms? An easy way to verify this is adding a Behavioral Voltage Source with ```V=time``` and plot that result as well. The voltage should be 0.9mV at t=0s.

Comment: To see the transient options in macOS version, when you edit the Spice directive, right-click somewhere in the text input box, select "Help me edit" then "Analysis Cmd" -- you'll have a similar UI.